# Port forwarding when router and modem are separate

Tags: router, port-forwarding, home-networking, modem

I am using two different devices for connecting to the Internet.

I have a [Motorola modem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JV9LUK) and a [DLink router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0081TXJ28), and get my Internet connection from Comcast.

Now I am trying to enable port forwarding to a laptop. Where should I try to do that? Will I need to do that in the router/modem/both? My laptop is going to run over Wi-Fi.

Comment: Just on the router, generally.

Answer (score 2):

The router. That modem is just going to be giving you an internet connection over your cable line.

You can find more information on how to set up your router for a specific application at [portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/DIR-826L/).

Comment: So the modem doesn't provide an IP address to the router?

Comment: @user250788, port-forwarding implies NAT: mapping private IPs to a single public IP. Your modem should be giving your router a public IP for you to manage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is modems that aren't just modems, and do NAT

Double NAT is more work with port forwarding and people usually try to avoid double NAT. (i.e. they have just their router device doing NAT).

You could unplug the modem from the wall, connect your comp to it directly, and make sure it isn't giving you a private ip to access its interface. If it is then I suppose it's doing NAT at least to some extent. If the modem is connected to the wall, you brave potentially connecting to the internet directly with just your OS's or other software firewall(comp doing PPP), then you could check more and do ipconfig and tracert to a website, see if any private addresses. Really the ideal may be the modem bridging, otherwise you have double NAT and port forwarding is more work.

An ideal is if your modem is a pure bridge, no NAT. Can even be no PPP. And the Router device you have does PPP(connecting to your ISP).

Your modem looks like it's just a modem

http://www.arrisi.com/modems/datasheet/SB5101u/SB5101u_User%20Guide_English.pdf

so you just have to configure your router.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how everything is set up, but I can only assume your router only bridges the wireless and wired connections together. You can easily check this if you only have a DHCP server running on your modem.

If that is the case, simply set up the port forwarding on the modem and all should be working fine.

Comment: Re your first paragraph, you write " I can only assume your router only bridges the wireless and wired connections together. You can easily check this if you only have a DHCP server running on your modem." <---- What has having a DHCP server on his 'modem' got to do with checking whether his router "bridges the wireless and wired connections together"?

Comment: If the DHCP server on the modem delivers IP addresses on the wireless network, it means that the modem can reach the network behind the router and that the router only functions as an access point. In that case, port forwarding on the modem will deliver the packets straight to the designated device, unless there is still some custom configuration on the router that would block the forwarded ports.

Comment: so you mean you can only assume his router is acting as a wireless access point + wired switch?  One could make a setup work like that(if, I suppose, his router has the option). But in his case his modem seems to be just a modem, "bridging" WAN and LAN. no NAT, no DHCP. So his upstream device is just a modem, and his downstream device would have to do  NAT. And by the way, you can have NAT without DHCP. That is common when port forwarding. So testing for DHCP may show the presence of NAT but the absence of DHCP won't mean the absence of NAT.